# HTML - Javascript connection to database

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, database

I want to create a small website in HTML / Javascript in our company and I'm trying to upload data to an Access database on the company network, but since I don't have administrator rights, I cannot use PHP, ASP or JSP to make the database connection work at server side. I also don't have WAMP running or anything, I merely write an HTML file with some CSS and Javascript, and use the directory structure to display my webpage. I don't have permission rights to install programs (roll out exe files) due to the company policy :-(. 
I'm dieing to use a database though (what can I do without??) and I feel very much blocked right now. I had a great idea in mind for our desk and I tried to avoid the general IT policy, because a development request takes too much time and it may not be delivered exactly the way I want it.

Does anyone have some solutions for me (in whatever language or database)?? 
This may be totally impossible, I don't know! I was hoping some genius could provide me a workaround! (Or hack the system? ;-) kidding)

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

You **must** use some sort of server side programming in order to update a database that lives on the server.

Javascript runs on the client (browser) and can't do this. Even in the client it will have limitations on what it can do:

- No connections to a local database (local storage not withstanding)
- No way to use the filesystem
- No control over other applications

No way around it.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is quite useless in your case.

Answer (score 1):

without using serverside language, you cannot access Database using HTML or Javascript. if you want to access database, you have to use some serverside language. or else you can use json file or csv or any xml file format to store data and access it via JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could write to a txt file.

Javascript is in basic a client side language. So i think it's impossible to create a database connection.

Comment: Maybe you can make some sort of changelog. 
It is possible to read a text file. So the javascript can be used to read all recently made changes and anticipate on that.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you people hear of [nodeJS?](http://nodejs.org)...
You can freely use JavaScript for database connection using node.